# Как менять текст в зависимости от выбранных элементов в MvxSpinner?

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, android-spinner, dropdown

Использую `mvvmcross` и `mvxspinner`.

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spMultiList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Users"
    app:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/cell_text_checkbox"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/selected_item"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_txt" />
```

Передаю коллекцию пользователей, использую кастомных `DropDownItemTemplate`: `app:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/cell_text_checkbox"` для вывода списка пользователей с чекбоксами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо чтобы пользователи которых я выбрал, были записаны через запятую вместо "Select please".

Как я могу это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если этот ответ будут лайкать, то помечу его как решение.

В общем как такого решения нет (или я не нашёл), сделал всё через небольшой костыль.

Использую `MvxSpinner` с кодом показанным выше. В нём использую темплейт `app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/selected_item"`. В темплейте `TextView` с пустым текстом `android:Text=""` (сделано это для того чтобы текст от спиннера не перекрывал наш `textView` о котором речь пойдёт дальше.)

Затем на основном лейауте, где располагается спиннер, добавляем `TextView` и размещаем его поверх спиннера. Задаём различные ограничения (чтобы текст не вылазил за ширину, высоту и т.п.) и байндим на стринговое свойство во вьюмоделе.

Во вьюмоделе подписываемся на изменение элементов в коллеции Пользователй. И как только происходит изменение (чекбоксик чекается), во вьюмоделе дергается нужный нам метод, в котором мы меняем текст для нашего `TextView`.

Спасибо за внимание ;)